# Ignoring StopAllAudio() in Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

There is an AudioSource with background music. After a certain action, StopAllAudio is activated. I want the background music not to turn off, how to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll just guess into the dark that you are using the `StopAllAudio` from [this thread](https://answers.unity.com/questions/194110/how-to-stop-all-audio.html) like

```
private AudioSource[] allAudioSources;

private void Awake() 
{
    allAudioSources = FindObjectsOfType<AudioSource>();
}

public void StopAllAudio() 
{
    foreach(var audioSource in allAudioSources) 
    {
        audioSource.Stop();
    }
}
```

So if you want to exclude a certain (or multiple) `AudioSource` from beeing stopped you could use

```
// configure this in the Inspector
// set the size and reference according AudioSource(s)
// e.g. your background music source
public List<AudioSource> doNotStopSources = new List<AudioSource>();

private AudioSource[] allAudioSources;

privtae void Awake() 
{
    allAudioSources = FindObjectsOfType<AudioSource>();
}

public void StopAllAudio() 
{
    foreach(var audioSource in allAudioSources) 
    {
        // ignore AudiioSource if it is in doNotStopSources
        if(doNotStopSources.Contains(audioSource)) continue;

        audioSource.Stop();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the audiomixer that is built into unity? You can have levels for "groups" you create, that you then assign to various sound sources, this allows you to mute, change volumes, add effects etc to specific groups.  Such as "environment","spells","NPC talk", "music"

For docs from unity see: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AudioMixer.html